# TeXstudio left panel buttons

Tags: texstudio

I have installed the last version of TeXstudio (2.12.8) but I don't have the greek letters icon ($\lambda$) in the left panel and I don't know how I can obtain it.
Moreover, I have seen other different icons in this bar, how can I add buttons in this left panel?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 2.12.8

There were some changes in that panel for version 2.12.8. (See for example https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/73.) If you choose the symbols panel (with the star icon, third from the top), you should find a panel that is split in two. In the lower part you can choose between different sets of symbols, such as operators and Greek letters from a drop-down. Judging by the second screenshot in https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/73#issuecomment-375181645, the default appears to be "Operators", click on the word "Operators" to choose a different set.

## 2.12.6

For older versions this was a bit different:

Right click anywhere on that bar, and you get a menu where you can choose which panels to show. (The same goes for any other toolbar.)

[image]

Comment: Thank for your reply but in my case there are not more options than the panels shown. I have updated the picture to show this.

Comment: @Kenobi Sorry, seems I'm still on 2.12.6. Judging by the discussion in https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/73 it appears that there has been some changes in this area for 2.12.8. If my quick read is right, the panel with the `*` symbol is split in two, and in the lower part you can choose between operators, Greek letters, and more.

Comment: OK perfect! I have found it. I was looking for the greek letters icon and I didn’t see the subpanels of symbols. Thanks