# What is the fastest way to type greek letters in TeXStudio?

Tags: texstudio, greek

The question is in the title. I am using TeXStudio for years now, and I find myself typing greek letters a lot (since I am a science student). What is the fastest way to do so, except start typing `\alpha` or `\varepsilon` and press enter as soon as I get correct autocomplete?

I am using a Windows 10, and I use 5 languages on my device. So clicking on windows+space twice to get greek keyboard and then thrice to get back english every now and then is also not much of a shortcut.

Can we have something like pressing `a will give \alpha and so on like in Sublime Text? Or any other keyboard shortcut possibly?

Comment: Perhaps the following is relevant [TeXstudio left panel buttons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424993/62792). The star menu can be set up to show greek symbols.

Comment: This is definitely possible in Linux, with Compose key sequences.

Comment: Does TeXStudio not support user-defined keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Adding to what @Davislor said: WinCompose allows for the same functionality on Windows. I am using a dedicated „Greek“ key for that purpose: `Greek + a => α`, `Greek + S => Σ` etc.

Comment: Adding to @Ingmar: The default sequence for a Greek letter in WinCompose is `AltGr` `*` then a letter, e.g. `AltGr` `*` `V` for Ω.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with vim, [VIM-LaTeX](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) would be a nice option for this. You can flexibly define your own shortcuts there. But for Greek letters there is already a mapping: `a through `z expand to `\alpha` through `\zeta` (see [3.5 Greek Letter Mappings](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/greek-letter-mappings.html)).

Comment: No I am not familiar with Vim and I don't want to spend time on learning anything new in the middle of a semester. (And as I already hinted in my question, I don't want to leave TeXStudio, since it provides many many other shortcuts as well for improving speed. Sublime Text has the same set of shortcuts otherwise, that you've highlighted in your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a macro for that. One is presented on official TeXStudio's wiki

https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Scripts#replace-characters-by-their-latex-equivalent-while-typing

[image]